# Typescript issue with dynamic props based on component key

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
export enum ComponentKeys {
    TEXT = 'TEXT',
    LIST = 'LIST',
    MODAL = 'MODAL',
}

type TextProps = {
    label: string;
}

type ListProps = {
    id: string;
    value: string;
}

type ModalProps = {
    heading: string;
}

const components = {
    [ComponentKeys.TEXT]: TextComponent,
    [ComponentKeys.LIST]: ListComponent,
    [ComponentKeys.MODAL]: ModalComponent,
}

export const MappedComponent = (props: { componentKey: ComponentKeys; componentProps: any }) => {
    const Component = components[props.componentKey];
    return <Component {...props.componentProps} />;
};
```

I am quite new to Typescript and trying to solve the issue below.

I am currently using **any** for componentProps, is there a better way to refactor this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Union Types` of those `Props` like **TextProps**. Be like:

`TextProps | ListProps | ModalProps`.

**Hint**: you can even use `String Literal Type` alongside some conditions to manufacture it.